# Replicate all column options for each entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL and all I need to populate a table automatically where the values from column2 are always present for each value in column 1. For example, for every new item inserted on Column1(Names) I want a pre-defined set of values to populate Column2(Illnesses) I have no idea what to call this process and all my google searches returned nothing.

As an example:

When John is added to the Database it creates a row, I want to automatically duplicate John and fill column2 it with the following pre-defined options

[image]

I hope I'm explaining myself ok...probably I'm not so apologies.

Comment: May I suggest that you learn at least the basics of ***data normalization*** before designing any real-life databases.

Comment: What you need for that is called a "trigger". Triggers are essentially pieces of code that you can configure to run whenever data is inserted, updated or deleted (i.e. instead OR after `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`). In your case you most likely need a trigger after `INSERT`.

Comment: To add to my comment from before, you might also get away with a "computed column" instead of a trigger. A computed column is something like a formula field in Excel.

Comment: What other data is in Illnesses table? What purpose does this table serve?

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks, very good, that comment changed my life and all my queries are now answered both around SQL and the meaning of life. Rest assured you've done your job right without even considering the multiple reasons why I might have ended up in a situation where without experience I still have to create this set of tables. There you go, take a cookie

Comment: @June7 I'm not too sure about the best approach, at the moment I have one tablewhere each unique Name is, and I want to generate a second table with the unique Name ID's and a least of Illnesses that repeats itself for every unique Name ID. Every Unique ID will have the same list of illnesses on the second table. I don't mind creating another table just for illnesses, but Im not sure how to make the list of illnesses repeat for each unique name ID.

Comment: I provided answer with example. Didn't answer questions.

Comment: @June7 thank you, didn't see your other reply under your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing a many-to-many data relationship which requires 3 tables. There should be a table of People and a table of Illnesses where in both each record is unique. Then a junction table PeopleIllnesses which should save PeopleID and IllnessID as foreign keys of the ID's from People and Illnesses.

You want to 'batch create' a set of records. Possibly need code in whatever app you are using to program interface (Access, vb.net, C#, etc). The new People record must first be committed to table. In VBA, code could be in click event of a button on data entry form for People and like:

```
Sub btnAddRecords_Click()
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO PeopleIllnesses(PeopleID, IllnessID) SELECT " & Me.tbxPID & ", IllnessID FROM Illnesses"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, there's a Table that contains the Unique People ID records, but there's no table for the Illnesses. The illnesses list will be always the same for every unique PeopleID, so there's no join or relationship between tables I think, I just need a table that will populate always the same illness list per PeopleID. When a new user is added, it will automatically populate the list of illnesses.

Comment: Why don't you create a table with those 5 illnesses to use suggested SQL? (I would still use IllnessID primary/foreign keys). Otherwise, hard code the illnesses into a looping structure or try @gotqn suggestion. I have no idea if it will actually create records in table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`. Something like this:

```
SELECT [name], Illness
FROM 
(
    VALUES ('John')
) Names ([name])
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES ('Flu')
          ,('Covid')
          ,('Common Cold')
          ,('Constipations')
          ,('Food Posoning')
) Illnesses(Illness)
```